# Is there a way to measure features from a point cloud?

Tags: meshlab

Can MeshLab generate dimensionally-accurate circles, holes, features, etc from a point cloud? I'm considering using MeshLab for some metrology work, and I need to compare 3D scans to nominal 3D models/part dimensions to verify manufacturing processes.
Also, if this is possible, can we export these features/measurements for a report?

Answer (score 0):

there!
After going through your proposal, I fully understood what your requirements are.
I'm going to explain my experience in extracting features from point cloud.
I got the point cloud of several mechanical parts such as spur gear, helical gear, aircraft propellers, and many other parts that have the specific design parameters such as diameter of circle...
I used FPP (fringe projection profilometry) to get the point cloud.
After getting the hole point cloud, I used LSODF (least squares orthogonal distance fitting) algorithm to extract the features from these point clouds.
In general, we know the model equation of the object that is represented by point coluds.
Say, you are going to extract the helical angle of the helical gear.
We got the point clouds of helical gear, so you already know the equation of helical gear represented in mathematically.
If we know the model equation and similar one and we have the measured point clouds of that objects, we can extract the features by using LSODF.

You can see that from this link.
https://www.researchgate.net/publication/221114214_Least_Squares_Orthogonal_Distance_Fitting_of_Implicit_Curves_and_Surfaces

Please share more information about your problems.